# Rails 3, data from join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

and table

```
product_category with product_id and category_id
```

, it working good then i put data to it, but how i need to get data for example by category?
category_id = 1 and all products by this category

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your join table needs be called categories_products
thats the rails default for the join table name, it is in alphabetical order so categories before products and they need to be plural.

once you have that working you can access the association by name like a method:

```
Category.find(1).products
```

gives you all products belonging to category of id 1

```
Product.find(1).categories
```

gives you all categories belonging to product of id 1

and so on...

Comment: thank you, i have correct table, where i need to write this? in view or controller and second thing if i want call products like this localhost/categories/1 i need to write Category.find(params[:id].products ?

Comment: and i am getting argument out of range

Comment: try starting up the console to test and see which particular part is wrong.  before rails 3 the command is ruby script/console  after rails 3 the command is rails c   then in the console you can type Category.find(1) to see if you get the error.

Comment: Category.find(params[:id]) should find the right category.  then calling products on it will give you its associated products.

Comment: Just as an FYI, the Rails convention for join tables is not alphabetical order of table names - it's to create a join table that is actually meaningful. If you have a `club` table and the `club` has many `users` who are `members` of the club, the join table would be `memberships` not `club_users`. The latter quickly becomes very confusing and forces you to use `ClubUsers` as your join model which is incredibly clunky

Comment: Just as another FYI, don't listen to anyone saying the convention is not alphabetical order; no matter how stupid the ordering is, if it is not alphabetical then rails will not find the table you are trying to use.  The rails documentation says it must be so: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#creating-join-tables-for-has_and_belongs_to_many-associations

Answer (score 0):

Try this...once you change the join table to categories_products.

```
<% category.products.each do |product| %>
<td><%= product.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

..............

define the scope in your model `scope :sorted, order('products.name ASC')` and the `@products = Products.sorted` in your controller.

That said I would recommend trying the `has_many products :through => categorization`

That should do the trick.

Comment: thank you, one more quastion, i have manufacturer_id in products table, i want to show name for manufacturer_id but not id